# Comparison of use of MVVM between WPF application and Winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, mvvm

I know that the `MVVM` design pattern is especially made for the WPF and Silverlight applications.

I look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364485/MVVM-Model-View-ViewModel-Patte) and I wonder :

1. Can we use the `MVVM` in winforms  normally as in a WPF applications? ie this statement is it true `Windows Form Applications can also have the advantages, and of course it doesn't mean the exact real Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern`?
2. What are the advantages of MVVM design pattern that I can't make use of if I apply this pattern in my `Winforms` application
3. What makes `MVVM` more suitable for `WPF` compared to `Winforms` ?

Comment: Too broad and opinion based. The main difference is the minimal support of DataBinding in WinForms compared to WPF

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd Can u explain more the difference of Databinding between Winforms and Wpf? Thanks

Comment: Please read about DataBinding in WPF and in WinForm before asking these things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can but to have a proper implementation you have to
   implement a lot of plumbing: I'm talking about all the binding
   details that in WPF are implemented out of the box.
2. Best advantage is to have the XAML free from code, easily skinnable by a designer ( not a programmer ) with, for example, Blend or something like that. In WInforms such a concept does not exists
3. Initial design: the two framework are created with different approach in mind.

Comment: 1/ What do u mean exactly by `you have to implement a lot of plumbing` ?  3/ what are these different approachs ? .Thanks

Comment: 1/ there is a lot of code to write in winform to have a binding as the wpf one. 2/ WPF is databinding centrinc, vs Winform is more presenter based.